# Searching XML for coordinates using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, api, windows-phone-7

I am not looking for any code, just advice on a particular aspect of a project.

I have an XML file that contains coordinates and the building name and I want to be able to capture the coordinates of where the person is (I'm going to be creating a mobile application so this is ok).

Is the senario above possible using a LINQ statement in C#? If so, is it possible to get a close match? i.e. if the person isn't exactly in the coordinates, show him/her the nearest match.

I'm NOT specifically looking for any code just any hints, tips, or advanced tutorials on LINQ would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate` class for this

```
List<GeoCoordinate> listTakenFromXml = ......
double lat = ......
double lon = ........
var nearest = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon).NearestPoint(listTakenFromXml);
```

---

```
public static class SoExtensions
{
    public static GeoCoordinate NearestPoint(this GeoCoordinate loc, IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> coords)
    {
        GeoCoordinate minLoc = null;
        double minDist = double.MaxValue;
        foreach (var c in coords)
        {
            var dist = c.GetDistanceTo(loc);
            if ( dist < minDist)
            {
                minDist = dist;
                minLoc = c;

            }
        }
        return minLoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The "listTakenFromXML" would therefore be the LINQ query of the XML file?

Comment: @Phorce Yes Linq To Xml can be very useful here.

Answer (score 0):

See [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and use the method which bests suits your situation. Once you have the calculation if you have a set of points in a list, then Linq to Object's extensions can help you with determining your logic as needed.